# Real-time Chat Application Issue For Saving Messages To Database

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, database, networking

**I'm currently developing a real-time chat application with Java and Node.js. As this app has real-time features in terms of chatting, I don't expect any delay for transferring messages between users. In my app, users have to verify their account tokens in order to send messages in real-time, and the messages should also be saved to the database. However, due to the delay of database operations in this process (for instance, verifying tokens), there'll be some delay in transferring messages in real-time. What can be a suitable approach for this issue? I don't want any delay or want very little delay for my real-time chat app.**

For example, even if it is related to real-time communucation, the following code will lead to some delay in message transferring due to asynchronous database operations:

```
const net = require("net");

const mysql2 = require("mysql2");

const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

require("dotenv").config();



const clients = [];



const server = net.createServer((socket) => {

    socket.on("connect", () => {

        clients.push(socket);

});



    socket.on("end", () => {

        const clientIndex = clients.indexOf(socket);



        if (clientIndex !== -1) {

      

      clients.splice(clientIndex, 1);

        }

    });



    socket.on("data", (data) => {

       const message = JSON.parse(data.toString());

            

             connection.query("SELECT token FROM sessions WHERE user_id = ?", [message.user_id], (e, r) => {

        if (!e && r.length > 0) {

               jwt.verify(process.env.SECRET, r[0].token, (err, decoded) => {

            if (!err) {

                   clients.forEach((client) => {

                               if (client !== socket) {

                        client.write(message.message);

                              }

                          });

                      }

                   }

                }

            });

    });

});



const connection = mysql2.createPool({

    host: process.env.HOST

    port: process.env.PORT,

    user: process.env.USER,

    password: process.env.PASSWORD,

    database: process.env.DATABASE

});



connection.getConnection((err) => {

    if (err) return;

    console.log("Connected to the database successfully!");

});
```